# How to convey "less than" constraint using type classes?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-families

I am trying to write a version of `take` that works on length-indexed vectors. This requires the number to take from to be less than or equal to the length of the vector.

This is the current version of my code:

```hs
data Nat where
    Zero :: Nat
    Succ :: Nat -> Nat

data SNat (n :: Nat) where
    SZero :: SNat Zero
    SSucc :: SNat n -> SNat (Succ n)

data Vec (n :: Nat) (a :: Type) where
    Nil  :: Vec Zero a
    Cons :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (Succ n) a

class (m :: Nat) >= (n :: Nat)
instance m >= Zero
instance m >= n => (Succ m >= Succ n)

take :: (m >= n) => SNat n -> Vec m a -> Vec n a
take (SZero  ) _         = Nil
take (SSucc n) (x `Cons` xs) = x `Cons` (take n xs)
```

However, I am getting this error which I am not sure how to solve:

```
    * Could not deduce (n2 >= n1) arising from a use of `take'
      from the context: m >= n
        bound by the type signature for:
                   take :: forall (m :: Nat) (n :: Nat) a.
                           (m >= n) =>
                           SNat n -> Vec m a -> Vec n a
        at src\AnotherOne.hs:39:1-48
      or from: (n :: Nat) ~ ('Succ n1 :: Nat)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   SSucc :: forall (n :: Nat). SNat n -> SNat ('Succ n),
                 in an equation for `take'
        at src\AnotherOne.hs:41:7-13
      or from: (m :: Nat) ~ ('Succ n2 :: Nat)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   Cons :: forall a (n :: Nat). a -> Vec n a -> Vec ('Succ n) a,
                 in an equation for `take'
        at src\AnotherOne.hs:41:17-27
      Possible fix:
        add (n2 >= n1) to the context of the data constructor `Cons'
    * In the second argument of `Cons', namely `(take n xs)'
      In the expression: x `Cons` (take n xs)
      In an equation for `take':
          take (SSucc n) (x `Cons` xs) = x `Cons` (take n xs
```

I have tried a few different iterations of the type class, using OVERLAPS and even INCOHERENT but I have not been able to fix it. HLS also tells me that the pattern matching is incomplete, saying that I am not matching `(SSucc SZero) Nil` and `(SSucc (SSucc _)) Nil`.

However if I try to write:

```hs
test = take (SSucc SZero) Nil
```

it correctly errors with `Couldn't match type ‘'Zero’ with ‘'Succ 'Zero’`, suggesting that my problem is specifically in the function definition, since from a few tests the API for the function seems correct.

Lastly I have been suggested to just use a type family for this, doing:

```hs
type (>=~) :: Nat -> Nat -> Bool
type family m >=~ n where
    m >=~ Zero        = True
    Succ m >=~ Succ n = m >=~ n
    _ >=~ _           = False
type m >= n = m >=~ n ~ True
```

Which does work, but I was trying to solve this using Haskell instances. As a side question, is there any benefit of one over the other?

Comment: The benefit of a type family is that it gets things working quickly, the benefit of a type class is that's how it "should" be, and the really correct thing to do is to have a GADT, optionally passed around as the sole method of a typeclass.

Comment: There is a video series by Richard Eisenberg on translating list operations to vectors: [@rae: How to program in types with length-indexed vectors: Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHS3Q-tRjFQ). I don't remember which video contains `take` but I'm pretty sure one of them does. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Iceland_jack That was the video series I was watching, Richard's `take` is slightly different though, using a type family `Min` to say that the result is the min of the SNat and the vector length. This was my attempt at making it slightly different. From watching the series though I think what I have to do is to somehow prove that my invariant holds using `:~:` and then case matching on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the interface of your `>=` class doesn't in any way express what it *means* for a number to be at least as great as another.

To do that, I would suggest refactoring the singleton type to clearly separate the two possible cases:

```
data SZero (n :: Nat) where
  SZero :: SZero 'Zero

data SPositive (n :: Nat) where
  SSucc :: SNat n -> SPositive ('Succ n)

type SNat n = Either (SZero n) (SPositive n)
```

Furthermore, we need to have a way to express rolling back the inductive steps on the type level. Here we need a type family, but it can be much simpler than your `>=~` one:

```
type family Pred (n :: Nat) :: Nat where
  Pred ('Succ n) = n
```

Notice this is not total! It's ok: type families can safely *point to nowhere*. You can still use them in a context where the compiler can infer that the clause that *is* there applies.

Now we can formulate the class. The crucial theorem that you noticed was missing was that in the `Succ` case, you can apply induction over the predecessors. More precisely, we only need to know that *n* is positive, in order to be able to step down the *m*≥*n* property to the predecessors of both numbers. I.e. the mathematical statement is

```
m≥n ∧ positive(n) ⟹ pred(m) ≥ pred(n).
```

We can now express exactly that, using the CPS trick to demote the implication arrow into the value-level:

```
class m>=n where
  atLeastAsPositive :: SPositive n -> (Pred m >= Pred n => r) -> r
```

For the `Zero` case, this theorem doesn't even apply, but that's no problem – we know there aren't any suitable singletons anyway, so we can safely use an empty case match:

```
instance m >= 'Zero where
  atLeastAsPositive s = case s of {}
```

The interesting case is the one of positive numbers. The way we have formulated the type, the compiler can easily connect the threads:

```
instance m >= n => ('Succ m >= 'Succ n) where
  atLeastAsPositive (SSucc _) φ = φ
```

And finally, we invoke that theorem in your `take` function:

```
take :: ∀ m n a . (m >= n) => SNat n -> Vec m a -> Vec n a
take (Left SZero) _         = Nil
take (Right s@(SSucc n)) (x `Cons` xs)
  = atLeastAsPositive @m s (x `Cons` (take n xs))
```

Comment: I think I understand what is going on, `atLeastAsPositive` is what is making the "proof" and reassuring ghc that the invariant does in fact hold right? It does seem a little cumbersome to have to transform SNat into a Sum of SZero and all the positive numbers,  I am guessing that is one of the reasons GHC.TypeNat uses the `m <=? n ~ True` method. Also, ghc still warns about incomplete pattern matches, does this mean the proof is partial or that GHC isnt smart enough to infer that all valid inputs have been given?

Comment: I suppose you could just as well leave the original `SNat` singletons and have a separate singleton type with `SSucc' :: SNat n -> SPositive ('Succ n)`, but that seems kind of redundant. — Yes, GHC is often not smart enough to infer that all valid inputs have been given, as soon as you're doing _computations_ on types. I always disable `-Wincomplete-patterns`, both because it often just doesn't work and because even truely incomplete patterns are a pretty good Agile way of avoiding unnecessary work and getting descriptive error messages for unimplemented case.

Comment: @leftaroundabout  Why the leading single quote in  'Zero  and  'Succ  ? Thanks.

Comment: @jpmarinier that's the general syntax for promoted constructors. Only, if there is no type named `Zero` in scope, GHC will automatically interpret it as `'Zero`, so technically it's only necessary in case you need to disambiguate between a type `A` and a promoted constructor `'A`. But IMO it's more consistent to always add the quotation mark explicitly.